# Restrict some users to update or view other users data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have users with role manager, and I only want them to update or view other users(employee) data that belong in the same department as the manager user. If the manager user is not in the same department as the user he's trying to update it should redirect the back.
i.e., the manager might try to change the user id in the URL, and I want to deny access to if that user belongs in another department.
I have all my roles and permissions set up.

> The Department field is in USER TABLE

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $team = User::where('id', $id)->with('roles')->first();

    return view('backend.user.team.show', compact('team'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user_roles = Role::all();
    $team = User::find($id);
    $business = Business::all();

    return view('backend.user.team.edit', compact('team', 'user_roles', 'business'))->with('user', auth()->user());
}
```

Comment: You should review https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `policies` and `gates`.

Take a look at the documentation:

[Writing policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies)

[Writing gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-gates)

Basically, you should do something like this:

Create a policy to handle your user permissions:

```sh
php artisan make:policy UsersPolicy
```

This command will create a `UsersPolicy` file within the `App/policies/` directory.

Open the `UsersPolicy` file and create a `checkUserDepartament` within that file:

```php
public function checkUserDepartament(User $user, User $userToBeManaged)
{
    return $user->departament === $userToBeManaged->departament;
}
```

The function above return true if the current logged in user departament is the same of the user you want to edit. Otherwise, return false.

Within your AuthServiceProvide:

```php
Gate::define('user-belongs-to-same-departament', 'App\Policies\UsersPolicy@checkUserDepartament');
```

To use the Gate, do something like this within your controller:

```php
use Gate; //At the top of the controller.
// I assume that $id is the id of the user you want to edit.
public function edit($id)
{
    if(Gate::allows('user-belongs-to-same-departament', User::find($id))){
        $user_roles = Role::all();
        $team = User::find($id);
        $business = Business::all();

        return view('backend.user.team.edit', compact('team', 'user_roles', 'business'))->with('user', auth()->user());

    }else {
        return response('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: check [this package](https://github.com/jungessolutions/laravel-acl) for groups (roles) and permissions management.